# bad gateway when expose service using treafik

Tags: kubernetes

I am using treafik(v2.0) to expose my eureka service,this is my treafik config:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: fat-eureka-route
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - match: Host(`k8s-fat-eureka.example.com`) 
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: eureka
          port: 8761
```

when I access eureka(in kubernetes namespace `dabai-fat`),it gives bad gateway tips like this:

```
[root@ops001 conf.d]# curl --header 'Host:k8s-fat-eureka.example.com' http://eureka:123456@172.19.150.82
Bad Gateway
```

what should I do to fix this problem? This is the eureka service yaml file:

```
{
  "kind": "Service",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "eureka",
    "namespace": "dabai-fat",
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/dabai-fat/services/eureka",
    "uid": "ee2949e2-dbef-4b45-868b-efc60f52bed4",
    "resourceVersion": "13217746",
    "creationTimestamp": "2020-02-01T16:55:54Z",
    "labels": {
      "app": "eureka"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "ports": [
      {
        "name": "server",
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "port": 8761,
        "targetPort": 8761
      },
      {
        "name": "management",
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "port": 8081,
        "targetPort": 8081
      }
    ],
    "selector": {
      "app": "eureka"
    },
    "clusterIP": "None",
    "type": "ClusterIP",
    "sessionAffinity": "None"
  },
  "status": {
    "loadBalancer": {}
  }
}
```

The service location is:

[image]

This is the eureka service file:

```
{
  "kind": "StatefulSet",
  "apiVersion": "apps/v1beta2",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "eureka",
    "namespace": "dabai-fat",
    "selfLink": "/apis/apps/v1beta2/namespaces/dabai-fat/statefulsets/eureka",
    "uid": "92eefc3d-4601-4ebc-9414-8437f9934461",
    "resourceVersion": "13319530",
    "generation": 14,
    "creationTimestamp": "2020-02-01T16:55:54Z",
    "labels": {
      "app": "eureka"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "replicas": 1,
    "selector": {
      "matchLabels": {
        "app": "eureka"
      }
    },
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "creationTimestamp": null,
        "labels": {
          "app": "eureka"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "eureka",
            "image": "registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/dabai_app_k8s/dabai_fat/soa-eureka:v1.0.0",
            "ports": [
              {
                "name": "server",
                "containerPort": 8761,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              },
              {
                "name": "management",
                "containerPort": 8081,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              }
            ],
            "env": [
              {
                "name": "APP_NAME",
                "value": "eureka"
              },
              {
                "name": "POD_NAME",
                "valueFrom": {
                  "fieldRef": {
                    "apiVersion": "v1",
                    "fieldPath": "metadata.name"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "APP_OPTS",
                "value": " --spring.application.name=${APP_NAME} --eureka.instance.hostname=${POD_NAME}.${APP_NAME} --registerWithEureka=true --fetchRegistry=true --eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=false --eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eureka-0.${APP_NAME}:8761/eureka/,http://eureka-1.${APP_NAME}:8761/eureka/"
              },
              {
                "name": "APOLLO_META",
                "valueFrom": {
                  "configMapKeyRef": {
                    "name": "fat-config",
                    "key": "apollo.meta"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "ENV",
                "valueFrom": {
                  "configMapKeyRef": {
                    "name": "fat-config",
                    "key": "env"
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "resources": {
              "limits": {
                "cpu": "2",
                "memory": "1Gi"
              },
              "requests": {
                "cpu": "2",
                "memory": "1Gi"
              }
            },
            "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
            "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
            "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent"
          }
        ],
        "restartPolicy": "Always",
        "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 10,
        "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
        "securityContext": {},
        "imagePullSecrets": [
          {
            "name": "regcred"
          }
        ],
        "schedulerName": "default-scheduler"
      }
    },
    "serviceName": "eureka-service",
    "podManagementPolicy": "Parallel",
    "updateStrategy": {
      "type": "RollingUpdate",
      "rollingUpdate": {
        "partition": 0
      }
    },
    "revisionHistoryLimit": 10
  },
  "status": {
    "observedGeneration": 14,
    "replicas": 1,
    "readyReplicas": 1,
    "currentReplicas": 1,
    "updatedReplicas": 1,
    "currentRevision": "eureka-57c8656b89",
    "updateRevision": "eureka-57c8656b89",
    "collisionCount": 0
  }
}
```

This is the treafik service yaml:

```
{
  "kind": "Service",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "traefik",
    "namespace": "kube-system",
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/traefik",
    "uid": "b2695279-2467-4480-aab5-a720a43951c1",
    "resourceVersion": "12750877",
    "creationTimestamp": "2020-01-29T10:26:34Z",
    "annotations": {
      "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"kind\":\"Service\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"name\":\"traefik\",\"namespace\":\"kube-system\"},\"spec\":{\"ports\":[{\"name\":\"web\",\"port\":80},{\"name\":\"websecure\",\"port\":443},{\"name\":\"admin\",\"port\":8080}],\"selector\":{\"app\":\"traefik\"}}}\n"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "ports": [
      {
        "name": "web",
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "port": 80,
        "targetPort": 80
      },
      {
        "name": "websecure",
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "port": 443,
        "targetPort": 443
      },
      {
        "name": "admin",
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "port": 8080,
        "targetPort": 8080
      }
    ],
    "selector": {
      "app": "traefik"
    },
    "clusterIP": "10.254.169.66",
    "type": "ClusterIP",
    "sessionAffinity": "None"
  },
  "status": {
    "loadBalancer": {}
  }
}
```

By the way,my kuubernetes(v1.15.2) dashboard(in `kube-system` namespace) works fine with this config:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-route
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
  tls:
    secretName: cloud-mydlq-tls
  routes:
    - match: Host(`kubernetes.example.com`) 
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: kubernetes-dashboard
          port: 443
```

This is the service eureka descibe output:

```
[root@ops001 conf.d]# kubectl describe service eureka -n dabai-fat
Name:              eureka
Namespace:         dabai-fat
Labels:            app=eureka
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=eureka
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                None
Port:              server  8761/TCP
TargetPort:        8761/TCP
Endpoints:         172.30.224.17:8761
Port:              management  8081/TCP
TargetPort:        8081/TCP
Endpoints:         172.30.224.17:8081
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

this is treafik logs output:

```
[root@ops001 traefik-deployment-yaml]#  kubectl logs --tail=10 traefik-ingress-controller-hx4xd --namespace kube-system
E0202 13:46:25.977450       1 reflector.go:125] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190718183610-8e956561bbf5/tools/cache/reflector.go:98: Failed to list *v1.Service: services is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "services" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E0202 13:46:25.978591       1 reflector.go:125] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190718183610-8e956561bbf5/tools/cache/reflector.go:98: Failed to list *v1alpha1.IngressRoute: ingressroutes.traefik.containo.us is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "ingressroutes" in API group "traefik.containo.us" at the cluster scope
E0202 13:46:26.972861       1 reflector.go:125] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190718183610-8e956561bbf5/tools/cache/reflector.go:98: Failed to list *v1alpha1.Middleware: middlewares.traefik.containo.us is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "middlewares" in API group "traefik.containo.us" at the cluster scope
E0202 13:46:26.973546       1 reflector.go:125] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190718183610-8e956561bbf5/tools/cache/reflector.go:98: Failed to list *v1beta1.Ingress: ingresses.extensions is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "ingresses" in API group "extensions" at the cluster scope
E0202 13:46:26.974483       1 reflector.go:125] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190718183610-8e956561bbf5/tools/cache/reflector.go:98: Failed to list *v1.Secret: secrets is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E0202 13:46:26.975571       1 reflector.go:125] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190718183610-8e956561bbf5/tools/cache/reflector.go:98: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: endpoints is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "endpoints" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E0202 13:46:26.976691       1 reflector.go:125] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190718183610-8e956561bbf5/tools/cache/reflector.go:98: Failed to list *v1alpha1.IngressRouteTCP: ingressroutetcps.traefik.containo.us is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "ingressroutetcps" in API group "traefik.containo.us" at the cluster scope
E0202 13:46:26.977765       1 reflector.go:125] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190718183610-8e956561bbf5/tools/cache/reflector.go:98: Failed to list *v1alpha1.TLSOption: tlsoptions.traefik.containo.us is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "tlsoptions" in API group "traefik.containo.us" at the cluster scope
E0202 13:46:26.978815       1 reflector.go:125] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190718183610-8e956561bbf5/tools/cache/reflector.go:98: Failed to list *v1.Service: services is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "services" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E0202 13:46:26.980811       1 reflector.go:125] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190718183610-8e956561bbf5/tools/cache/reflector.go:98: Failed to list *v1alpha1.IngressRoute: ingressroutes.traefik.containo.us is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "ingressroutes" in API group "traefik.containo.us" at the cluster scope
```

Comment: can you provide the service yaml for eureka

Comment: I give the service yaml file@ArghyaSadhu

Comment: you have to provide service yaml for eureka

Comment: That is StatefulSet...I am looking for service yaml for a service with name eureka because you are referring to this service in the ingressroute. can you run kubectl describe svc eureka and provide the output?

Comment: Is the pod yaml of eureka?@ArghyaSadhu

Comment: No not the pod yaml...you must have created a service with name "eureka" otherwise it will not work because you are referring to service "eureka" in the ingressroute. You may have put the service in the pod yaml itself...so just provide it

Comment: Can you run kubectl describe service eureka and provide the output?

Comment: What does the log in traefik pod says when you hit the eureka url?

Comment: Have you authorized Traefik to use kubernetes API using ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding resources?